# How to read reads a file containing text. Read each line and send it to the output file, preceded by line numbers

Tags: java

this program does not create the files

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Input file: ");
String Mary = in.next();
System.out.print("Output file: ");
String outMary = in.next();

File inFile = new File ("Mary.txt");
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(inFile);
PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("Mary2.txt");

while (inputFile.hasNext())
{
  String input = in.nextLine();
  outFile.println(input);
}
```

I want to read a file I created and copy its contents into another with line numbers before each line.

Comment: Mary had a little lamb
Whose fleece was white as snow.
And everywhere that Mary went,
The lamb was sure to go!

then the program produces the output file(each on new line after number)

/* 1 */ Mary had a little lamb
/* 2 */ Whose fleece was white as snow.
/* 3 */ And everywhere that Mary went,
/* 4 */ The lamb was sure to go!

Comment: You're not reading from `inputFile`.

Comment: how do I do that then

Comment: The same way you read from `in`.

Comment: How would I read "inputFile" like "in"
like this: String input = inputFile.nextLine();

Comment: This is the error message if this helps:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Mary.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: That means there's no such file.

Comment: What if I created a notepad file with the information inside and call the file Mary.txt?

Comment: You can't just put it anywhere and expect your code to find it.

Answer (score 1):

try this code, this will create new file for output. Note, this will erase file, if it existed before writing

```
           File inFile = new File("Mary.txt");
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(inFile);

          try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("Mary2.txt")))) {
              int i=0;
              while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
                  String input = inputFile.next();
                  bw.write(i+"\\ ");
                  i++;
              }
              bw.flush();
          }
```